# Change DataGrid Column display value in AutoGeneratingColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have `dataGrid.ItemsSource` bound to a list of EntityItem, `Client`, that containt another EntityItem, `Company`.

When my `dataGrid` is displayed, in my `Company` Column, I have the type of my object (`System.Data.Entity.` ...) I would like instead to display my `Company.Name`.

In WindowsForm I could just do :

```
e.Value = ((Company)(dgv["Company", e.RowIndex].Value)).Name;
```

But I can't find a way to do in properly in WPF.

For now I have :

```
private void dataGridUsers_AutoGeneratingColumn_1(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid dgv = (DataGrid)sender;
        if (e.PropertyName == "Company")
        { 
            if (e.PropertyType == typeof(Company))
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

So I can make sure I'm on the right column, but now I'm stuck, I don't know how to change the way I want the column to display the data ... 
I tried to look into `e.PropertyDescriptor` but it's only to Get the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs` object has `Column` property which contains a generated `DataGridColumn` instance. Concrete type is `DataGridTextColumn`, which has `Binding` property.

You can change binding path to work with `Column.Name` property

```
private void DataGridOnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Company")
    {
        var c = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
        var b = (Binding)c.Binding;
        b.Path = new PropertyPath("Company.Name");
    }
}
```